# sudo/suid non-root nesting fails

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-3.x, sudo

I have a python script (which must be called as root), which calls a bash script (which must be called as non-root), which sometimes needs to call sudo.  This does not work - the "leaf" sudo calls give the message "$user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."  How can I make this work?

The code (insert your non-root username in place of "your_username_here"):

tezt.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import pwd
import subprocess

def run_subshell_as_user(cmd_args, user_name=None, **kwargs):
  cwd = os.getcwd()
  user_obj = pwd.getpwnam(user_name)

  # Set up the child process environment
  new_env = os.environ.copy()
  new_env["PWD"] = cwd
  if user_name is not None:
    new_env["HOME"] = user_obj.pw_dir
    new_env["LOGNAME"] = user_name
    new_env["USER"] = user_name

  # This function is run after the fork and before the exec in the child
  def suid_func():
    os.setgid(user_obj.pw_gid)
    os.setuid(user_obj.pw_uid)

  return subprocess.Popen(
    cmd_args, 
    preexec_fn=suid_func, 
    cwd=cwd,
    env=new_env,
    **kwargs).wait() == 0

run_subshell_as_user(["./tezt"], "your_username_here") # <-- HERE
```

tezt:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo ls -la /root
```

Then run it as:

```
sudo ./tezt.py
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?  The user can run sudo under normal circumstances.  Why does "user -sudo-> root -suid-> user" work fine, but then when you try to sudo from there it fails?

Comment: Why do the setuid()/setgid() calls yourself, rather than using sudo to drop privileges there? `["sudo", "-u", "your_username_here", "--", cmd_args]`

Comment: Consider also switching to `setreuid()` and `setregid()`.

Comment: With `setreuid/setregid` I get an unhelpful exception out of the preexec_fn function.  But with prepending sudo to the command argument it seems to work!  Still not sure what's going on here, but thanks for the solution, @CharlesDuffy!

Comment: that said, on MacOS X, this *does* work **exactly** as given; can't repro the issue there.

Comment: ahh, good to hear, will add the comment as an answer, then.

Comment: Must come down to some strange Debian- or linux-specific thing then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using `sudo` to drop privileges rather than doing so yourself -- that's a bit more thorough where possible, modifying effective as opposed to only real uid and gid. (To modify the full set yourself, you might try changing `setuid()` to `setreuid()`, and likewise `setgid()` to `setregid()`).

...this would mean passing something to Popen akin to the following:

```
["sudo", "-u", "your_username_here", "--"] + cmd_args
```